# Time Complexity of Nested Loops that Don't Iterate The Same Amount Of Times

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I don't understand why the time complexity of the following algorithm is O(N^2) and not O(N*i)...?

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    a[i] *= 2;
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        d[i][j] = a[i] * c[j];
}
```

I would greatly appreciate it if someone would be able to point me in the right direction...

Comment: `i` is not a free parameter but a loop variable. What should `O(N*i)` complexity mean?

Answer (score 2):

It does not matter if a nested loop does not iterate the same amount of a outer loop. The overall time complexity is `O(N^2)`.

```
C = O(N) + O(0 + 1 + 2 + ... + N - 1)
```

`O(N)` is `a[i] *= 2`, the right part is the inner loop.
This is a sum of the arithmetic mean progression:

```
C = O(N) + O(N * (N - 1) / 2) = O(N) + O(N^2/2 - N/2) = O(N) + O(N^2) + O(N^2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because here the loops are simple, it's easy to count all actions done.

The `a[i] *= 2` is done `N` times.
The `d[i][j] = a[i] * c[j]` is done:

- when `i==0` : 0 times
- when `i==1` : 1 times
- ...
- when `i==N-1` : `N`-1 times.
  The total is: `N + 0 + 1 + ... + N-1` = `N + (N-1)(N-2)/2` = `(1/2)(N^2) - N/2 + 1`.

**For `O()` we consider only the highest power and ignore constant coefficients, here it is `O(N^2)`.**

Why this? We want to know what happens when `N` is big.
E.g: `N = 1,000` => exact number is `(1/2)(N^2) - N/2 + 1` = `499,501`.
`N = 10,000` => exact number is `(1/2)(N^2) - N/2 + 1` = `49,995,001`.
We see that for `N` 10 times bigger, result is about 100 times bigger. It is **`O(N^2)`**.

**We can do shorter, rereading the code:**
There is a loop on `N`, and inside a loop limited by `i` and `i` is varying like N. It is a **`O(N^2)`** process.